# Override application properties of spring application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, java-8

Currently we developing a web application on we use **spring framework**, this application contains several modules, so we chose to put all the configuration in a  module named "***shared-module***" when we using the IDE we can specify the propority file of profile but when we try to launch this application outside of IDE we can not point to the correct property file.

Application strucuture:
**shared-module**--(injected)-->**application.jar**

[image]

Comment: see [this](https://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/)

Comment: This should normally work out of the box with Spring, but you need to make sure that you properties files are not overrided by the properties of another module. Can you shared the folders structure of your application?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond: I shared the folder strucuture.

Comment: How do you load localhost.properties?

Comment: From IDE I use spring.config.location=path/to-shared-module

Answer (score 0):

See Externalized Configuration properties order described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). This documentation have clear description of supported application and profile specific properties. Please provide additional information if it does not address specific scenario you've problem with.